# $f(a)<f(b)$. Then for any points $x$ in the neighborhood balls of $a$ and any point $y$ in the neighborhood of $b$ we have $f(x)<f(y)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$.

$a,b$ are two constants such that
$f(a)<f(b)$.

Show that: there exist an epsilon neighborhood ball $B(a)$ centered at $a$ and an epsilon neighborhood ball $B(b)$ centered at $b$  such that for any $x\in B(a)$ and for any $y\in B(b)$ we have $f(x)<f(y)$

I think the claim is very basic and intuitive.

---

My try:

Step1: Since $f(a)<f(b)$ and $f$ is continuous, there exists $c$ such that $f(a)<f(c)<f(b)$

(Are there any named theorem for this or is this a trivial fact?)

Step2: there exists an epsilon neighborhood ball $B(a)$ centered at $a$ such that for all $x\in B(a)$, $f(x)<f(c)$

Step3: there exists an epsilon neighborhood ball $B(b)$ centered at $b$ such that for all $y\in B(b)$, $f(y)>f(c)$

That is, we find the two balls.

Comment: This is fine and what you used in Step 1 is the Intermediate value Property.

Comment: You should explain why these balls necessarily exist. **Hint:** take sufficiently small balls inside $f^{-1}(I)$ where $I$ is an interval containing $f(a)$ and not $f(b)$, then do something similar in the complement of $I$ (which necessarily contains $f(b)$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Step 1: Since $f(a)<f(b)$ and $f$ is continuous, there exists $c$ such that $f(a)<f(c)<f(b)$

This is true because $\Bbb R^n$ is *connected* and the continuous image of a connected set is connected, so that $f(\Bbb R^n)$ is an *interval* in $\Bbb R$. (It also follows from the “Intermediate Value Theorem” applied to $g:[0, 1] \to \Bbb R, g(t) = f((1-t)a + tb)$.)

But this “Step 1” is *not needed:* Just define
$$
 d = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{2} > 0 \, .
$$
Then use the continuity of $f$ to find $\epsilon_1 > 0$ and  $\epsilon_2> 0$ such that
$$
 \forall x \in B_{\epsilon_1}(a): \, |f(x) - f(a)| < d \\
 \forall y \in B_{\epsilon_2}(b): \, |f(y) - f(b)| < d \\
$$
Conclude that
$$
 f(x) < f(a) + d = \frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2} = f(b) -d < f(y)
$$
for $ x \in B_{\epsilon_1}(a)$ and $y \in B_{\epsilon_2}(b)$.

In other words: $v = \frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}$ takes the role of your $f(c)$ in Step 2 and Step 3, but you don't need the fact that the value $v$ is attained by $f$.